# Oracle pivot query used to display results in the below specified format

Tags: oracle

I have written a pivot query as below. I am using this query in apex to generate a report.In the report, we have two date pickers configured as start date and end date. Depending on what start date and end date user inputs, those many dynamic columns of a range of dates should be generated. Though pivot in oracle does not allow to put subquery of substitution variables in the for clause of the pivot, in apex I have the provision of using a substitution variable. This is the reason I used pivot in my query. Please find the query below:

```
SELECT *
FROM
  (SELECT PROCESSNAME,
    CASE
      WHEN STATUS=5
      THEN 'COMPLETED'
      WHEN STATUS=1
      THEN 'WAITING'
      WHEN STATUS=11
      THEN 'INVALID PRERUN'
      WHEN STATUS=10
      THEN 'STOP BY CONDITION'
      WHEN STATUS=6
      THEN 'STOPPED'
      WHEN STATUS=4
      THEN 'RUNNING'
      WHEN STATUS=7
      THEN 'STOP BY ERROR'
    END AS STATUS,
    TRUNC(startrundate) date1
  FROM EXPORT_TABLE
  WHERE TRUNC(startrundate) BETWEEN to_date('23-apr-2017','dd-mon-yyyy') AND to_date('25-apr-2017','dd-mon-yyyy')
  AND processname = 'JOB1'
  ORDER BY processname
  ) pivot ( COUNT(date1) FOR date1 IN ('23-apr-2017','24-apr-2017','25-apr-2017') )
```

-- here i have hardcoded the dates, but in apex ill pass this as substitution variable for which i write a query to dynamically generated the range of dates.

The issue is, for a particular Job I want to display all the details in one row only. But my above query is splitting into rows for a different status.This is because I have considered the status in my query.

```
PROCESSNAME          STATUS             23-APR-2017 24-APR-2017  25-APR-2017

 JOB1                STOP BY CONDITION     2             0          0

 JOB1                COMPLETED             0             1          0
```

Ideally what i want is the status of the job for each day in the same row like below:

```
PROCESSNAME  23-APR-2017          24-APR-2017   25-APR-2017

JOB1    STOP BY CONDITION    COMPLETED      NA
```

Please let me know what changes are required to achieve this.

Thanks and Regards

Answer (score 0):

Here is a version that gives you a similar, but different result.  Instead of the status in the row, the statuses are the row headers with the date the job achieved the status is in the row data.  I'm using MAX() on the date for the status.

```
SELECT *
FROM
  (with export_table(processname, status,startrundate) as
        (select 'JOB1', 10, to_date('04/23/2017','MM/DD/YYYY') from dual union all
         select 'JOB1', 10, to_date('04/24/2017','MM/DD/YYYY') from dual union all
         select 'JOB1', 11, to_date('04/24/2017','MM/DD/YYYY') from dual union all
         select 'JOB1', 5, to_date('04/25/2017','MM/DD/YYYY') from dual
        )
    SELECT PROCESSNAME,
    CASE
      WHEN STATUS=5
      THEN 'COMPLETED'
      WHEN STATUS=1
      THEN 'WAITING'
      WHEN STATUS=11
      THEN 'INVALID PRERUN'
      WHEN STATUS=10
      THEN 'STOP BY CONDITION'
      WHEN STATUS=6
      THEN 'STOPPED'
      WHEN STATUS=4
      THEN 'RUNNING'
      WHEN STATUS=7
      THEN 'STOP BY ERROR'
    END AS STATUS,
    TRUNC(startrundate) date1
  FROM EXPORT_TABLE
  WHERE TRUNC(startrundate) BETWEEN to_date('23-apr-2017','dd-mon-yyyy') AND to_date('25-apr-2017','dd-mon-yyyy')
  AND processname = 'JOB1'
  ORDER BY processname
  ) pivot ( max(date1) FOR status in ('COMPLETED','WAITING','INVALID PRERUN','STOP BY CONDITION','STOPPED','RUNNING','STOP BY ERROR'))
```